# Reveal collapse button from right when scroll down with Framer motion

Tags: framer-motion

I would like to appear a hamburger button from the right when scrolling down

```js
"use client";
import { motion, useScroll, useTransform } from "framer-motion";

export default function Header() {

  let { scrollY } = useScroll();
  let y = useTransform(scrollY, [0, 1], ["0px", "200px"]);
  return (
    <header>
      <div className="header-inner">
        <a href="/"><img alt="Logo" src="/logo.png" /></a>

        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/about" className="nav-item">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/careers" className="nav-item">Careers</a></li>

            <motion.li
              initial={{ right: 200 }}
              style={{ y }}
              transition={{ ease: "easeInOut" }}
            >
              <button aria-label="Hamburger" className="nav-button">
                Collapse button
              </button>
            </motion.li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

My code is like this and I am confused about how to accomplish this. What should I do to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have some improvements for this purpose with the `useMotionValueEvent` as:

```js
"use client";
import {
  motion,
  useScroll,
  useAnimation,
  useMotionValueEvent,
} from "framer-motion";

export default function Header() {
  let { scrollY } = useScroll();
  let anim = useAnimation();
  useMotionValueEvent(scrollY, "change", (latest) => {
    if (latest > 0) {
      anim.start({ opacity: 1, left: 0 });
    } else {
      anim.start({ opacity: 0, left: 199 });
    }
  });
  return (
    <header>
      <div className="header-inner">
        <a href="/"><img alt="Logo" src="/logo.png" /></a>

        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/about" className="nav-item">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/careers" className="nav-item">Careers</a></li>

            <motion.li animate={anim}>
              <button aria-label="Hamburger" className="nav-button">
                Collapse button
              </button>
            </motion.li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

It feels like I've found a solution, but I'm open to your suggestions if you have a better approach.

Thanks again.